# Как взять переменную из метода класса родителя?

Tags: c++, наследование, методы

у меня есть класс Trap

```
    class Trap
{
    protected:
        int down;
        int up;
public:

    Trap(int Down, int Up)
    {
        down=Down;
        up=Up;
    }
     float Sum();
};

    float Trap::Sum()
    {   
    float sum=1.*(down+up)/2;
    return sum;
    }
```

И класс TrapC

```
 class TrapC: public Trap
{
    protected:
    int h;
public:
    TrapC(int Down, int Up, int H): Trap(Down, Up)
    {
        h=H;
    }
    float S();

};

 float TrapC::S()
 {
    float s=(1.*(down+up)/2)*h;
    return s;
 }
```

как вы видите я в классе trap в методе sum нахожу *полусумму оснований*, а в классе trapc надо найти площадь. площадь трапеции есть *полусумма оснований* умноженная на высоту. но я не знаю как взять переменную sum из метода Sum и использовать ее в методе S наследника и мне приходится по сути переписывать пример. как сделать так, чтобы он эту sum увидел и метод сократился?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вызвать...

```
float TrapC::S()
{
    float s=Sum()*h;
    return s;
}
```

Вопрос - почему стороны и высота - `int` - не задаю...

Comment: да просто так )